# How to apply changes from a deleted file in a rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose we start with

[Init](https://github.com/MaikKlein/git-rebase/tree/a044081d266869c103d28eb8b1b315aaa33da2f2)

```
// file
Foo
Bar
```

We then start a new branch [refactor](https://github.com/MaikKlein/git-rebase/tree/fcbd58d61324f4b63ea97ae52c6d4e51e3d70539) and push a [PR](https://github.com/MaikKlein/git-rebase/pull/1).

It moves `Foo` to a new file `foo` and `Bar` to a new file `bar`.

Now the master changes

```
// file
Foo123
Bar
```

And the [PR](https://github.com/MaikKlein/git-rebase/pull/1) now has a merge conflict.
When I do a rebase I also get the conflict and this is how it looks in [magit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR7yP.png).

How do I know that `Foo` changed to `Foo123`? In such a simple case it shouldn't be hard but consider that `file` is several 1000 loc and the PR is sitting there for a month and other pople make changes to `file`.

My apporach is very error prone, when I encounter a deleted file I look all the commits  that touched the file and then copy paste the changes accordingly and then remove the file  with `git rm file`, but of course I sometimes overlooked a few changes. Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git show --name-status
```

to see what's been renamed or copied.  It'd be better if more commands identified renames, but `git show --name-status` (and its equivalent `git log --no-walk --name-status`) do identify them.

Comment: Note that `git show` runs `git diff` and it's `git diff` that finds renames and/or copies. Copy-finding is always disabled by default, while rename-finding is enabled by default since Git version 2.9, but not earlier. You can configure `diff.renames` and `diff.renameLimit` to alter the default `git diff` rename-finding behavior, as far back as I go with Git (1.5.something).